# Missing recommended icon file - The bundle does not contain an app icon for iPad of exactly '152x152' pixels, in .png f

Tags: ipad, app-store-connect, ios7

I got a message for my IPad only app

Missing recommended icon file - The bundle does not contain an app icon for iPad of exactly '152x152' pixels, in .png format

I did include a icon-76.png and a icon-76@2x.png of exactly 152x152

and I included icon-76.png in my info.plist

Is this a bug of mine or of theirs ?

My question is similar to others but I could not find the same

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18736954/missing-recommended-icon-file-the-bundle-does-not-contain-an-app-icon-for-ipho

Comment: @tipycalFlow I did see the above thread but felt it is not the same.

Comment: Did you include it in `CFBundleIcons` key, which is the same key for the other icon files?

Comment: I think the issue may have resolved itself I resubmitted my binary and did not receive the message a second time. I included my info.plist screen shot above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was really obvious in the end I had mixed up my upper and lower case i

I named all my icons correctly and stopped mixing upper and lower case I found the problem.

Also Xcode 5 makes it much easier to spot the mistake.

Answer (score 2):

change your icon-76@2x.png file to open in any other image editor tool and save and rebuild your app it may be working

Comment: Thanks for the answer I cannot test if it works, since it was only on submit to ITunes. Hope you help others finding this, I will upvote for attemting but not mark correct