# Warning in uploading build on iTunes Store

Tags: iphone, icons, itunes, release, ios7

> Missing recommended icon file - The bundle does not contain an app
>   icon for iPhone / iPod Touch of exactly '120x120' pixels, in .png
>   format.

I am using xcode 4.6.3  and I am creating app for iOS 4.3 and above, till iOS 6.1, as there is no option for iOS 7 in xcode 4.6.3. But it is condition for iOS 7 to have icon of pixel '120* 120', then why it is showing warning for my app.

I do not have icon of pixel `120*120` . Is there any way to skip from this error. Please tell me the solution or Is it compulsory to add icon?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to check Xcode version you are using, In Terminal run the following command

```
xcode-select -print-path
```

then try to check is this the Xcode 4.6.3 or below version if not change the path

```
sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
```

where Xcode.app is Xcode 4.6.3 or below version Path.

after switching the xcode version try uploading, this may fix your problem

if you have beta version of XCode 5 then it gives warning

Answer (score 3):

No, there is not way to skip this warning. If you build with the *iOS 6 SDK* you can still add the need icon, just add the 120x120  icon to the `CFBundleIconFiles` array in your `info.plist`.

Comment: No to what? Can you clarify this answer. My understanding for the error is that it is a recommendation. The app won't get rejected because of not having 120x120 icon. When you build with iOS7 sdk later you add all the required icons. Correct me if I am wrong?

Comment: @graver I've not been able to upload any app without the 120x120 icon since last week. There is noway to skip the warning (error in my case) thus you should just add the icon.

Comment: Weird, I did upload yesterday, it uploaded fine, received the error through email, but the app is in waiting for review status. The email states that the app delivery is successful but I may wish to correct to issue with the next delivery..

Answer (score 2):

If you will remove this warning that will be in your own favor because from now onwards its era of `iOS7`. Your app will run on all devices . It is just a HD icon which will show on `itunes`. So Apple is suggesting you to make it happen by making little more effort. Resize your icon for retina in 120x120 from [Here](http://www.picresize.com/) and add it in project.Update info.plist and then upload.

For updating info.plist refer to [`THIS Question On StackOverflow`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18736954/missing-recommended-icon-file-the-bundle-does-not-contain-an-app-icon-for-ipho)

Comment: That's actually not 100% correct. Your app _will_ run on iOS 7 as well as on earlier versions. I had the same warning but the app got approved now it's on appstore since monday. Runs fine on iOS 7 gm without the 120x120 icon.

Comment: Runs fine but icon doesnt look like it should look

Answer (score 2):

Well, if you are uploading your binary from `Xcode 4.6.3`. You will definitely get this warning.
**However Your app will not be rejected**. I also got this warning from apple but my app was published. **But it is highly recommended to add the required 120pixel icon** .
You can do so by

Either update your `Xcode` to `Xcode 5` and build your binary from there. 
Or add 120 pixel icon file in `.plist` file of your application.