# What is the apple URL for the new iOS 7 app icons?

Tags: icons, app-store, ios7

I am looking for the URL for the new iOS7 styled app icons.

Previously to get the URL for the app icons I would get the "artwork512" value from the public itunes lookup api (e.g use http://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=281796108&country=AU).

Then using this "artwork512" value I would append the string ".128x128-75" before the filetype at the end of the URL string.

for example:

original artwork512 URL: http://a758.phobos.apple.com/us/r30/Purple4/v4/d2/60/9d/d2609dce-a7e2-4da0-f930-0c767cf41f75/mzl.bqfiswfc.png

stylised app icon URL: http://a758.phobos.apple.com/us/r30/Purple4/v4/d2/60/9d/d2609dce-a7e2-4da0-f930-0c767cf41f75/mzl.bqfiswfc.128x128-75.png

Does anyone know what the new suffix is to get the iOS7 styled icons? i.e What should the ".128x128-75" string be changed to?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18736954/missing-recommended-icon-file-the-bundle-does-not-contain-an-app-icon-for-ipho/18737063#18737063

Comment: @kirtimali thanks but this doesn't have any reference to the URL apple uses to store the stylised version of the app icon that is used in the app store. I am not submitting an app, I am just looking for that URL.

Comment: check https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/App-RelatedResources/App-RelatedResources.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH6-SW1