# Missing Files: The bundle does not contain an app icon for iPad of exactly '76x76' pixels

Tags: ios, xcode, ios7

I have uploaded an app targeting ios 6.1 and earlier and it is in review, and I got an email notifying me that App is missing following files:

```
Missing recommended icon file - The bundle does not contain an app icon for iPhone / iPod Touch of exactly '120x120' pixels, in .png format. 

Missing recommended icon file - The bundle does not contain an app icon for iPad of exactly '76x76' pixels, in .png format. 

Missing recommended icon file - The bundle does not contain an app icon for iPad of exactly '152x152' pixels, in .png format.
```

Also, I looked into this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18736954/missing-recommended-icon-file-the-bundle-does-not-contain-an-app-icon-for-ipho). But nothing is clearly mentioned that if I don't upload icons for ios 7 then my app would be **rejected or not ?  As my app is targeting ios 6.1 and earlier.**

Plaese help me on this.

Thanks.

Comment: check my answer at Here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18736954/missing-recommended-icon-file-the-bundle-does-not-contain-an-app-icon-for-ipho/18737063?noredirect=1#comment27948792_18737063

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your app may work great on iOS 6.1 and earlier, but as Apple is now accepting applications that work on iOS 7 as well, you also need to also provide the iOS7 icon sizes that the store is expecting ***today***.

Comment: What my point is that if you can suggest me that without ios 7 icons my app would be accepted or rejected?

Comment: I'm looking at Apple's [official Icon & Image Sizes document](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconMatrix.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH27). 76x76 is what the iPad 2 (standard resolution) is looking for and 152x152 is what iPad Retina Display (iPad 3 & iPad 4) is expecting. 120 x 120 is what is on the phone.  How hard would it be add icons that conform to these sizes?  You want this to make it through review smoothly, right?

Comment: Cool. So just adding these new icons in the **Plist** would work for me? Also is there any specific name for them as my earlier icon are named as **AppName-57.png** ? Same would work for the new one also? Right?

Comment: [This Apple Q&A should give you the answers you need](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1686/_index.html). I hope this helps!

Comment: If you're using Photoshop to create your icons, this is an incredibly useful Action sheet to design and generate iOS7 icons: http://appicontemplate.com/ios7

Comment: Hey apple, there's only 176 different image sizes you support in here. How about just letting us provide an SVG and scale it yourselves. :-)