# Unable to authenticate the package: 721772200.itmsp

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, ios7, itunes

I am writing because I have a serious problem - I have bought the Commander Cool game on the cartoonsmart site. However, a serious problem occured. The application cannot be accepted by the iTune Connect validation. I tried to publish it from two different developer accounts and the error still occurs. The error suggests some problems with the certificate but I am sure it is 100% right because I have published more than 20 apps in the App Store as for now. I ask you for help because you are my last hope. The only thing I changed was to add armv6 in Valid Architectures because without it the app could not load.

Error is displayed via iTunes Connect:

"The following issues were found during validation:
Apple's web service operation was not successful
Unable to authenticate the package: 721772200.itmsp
ERROR ITMS-9000: "The bundle 'com.   .   ' at bundle path 'Payload/CommanderCool.app is not signed using an Apple submission certificate." at SoftwareAssets/SoftwareAsset (MSItmspSoftwareAssetPackage)?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19428700/unable-to-authenticate-the-package-727047181-itmsp

Comment: In my case Using Xcode 5.1.1 and iOS 7 I was able to successfully upload by removing the `armv6` architecture from the target.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you have additional errors like a missing 120x120 icon, if that is the case you should follow this

['Missing recommended icon file - The bundle does not contain an app icon for iPhone / iPod Touch of exactly '120x120' pixels, in .png format'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18736954/missing-recommended-icon-file-the-bundle-does-not-contain-an-app-icon-for-iph)

Fix other problems and then you could be able to submit your app, I was having the same problem.

Comment: 'Missing recommended icon file' is only a Warning no an Error

Comment: This answer is correct - solving whatever other issue they warn you about will remove this error.

Answer (score 0):

Check the icon file name in Plist file. This may be occur due to wrong icon file name.

Answer (score 0):

Move your icons and splashs to asset catlogs.
I was also facing this problem in xcode 5, actually i was trying to build code which was written in previous version of xcode (4.3 i guess).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error. In my case, the iPhone 5 was conected.
Steps: 
Disconnect the phone.
Select IOS Device (in simulators).
Then archive.