# Unable to authenticate the package : 727047181.itmsp

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, app-store

I have upload build in app store after archive the file it will goes to uploading builds on that time i got this error

1.Apples web services operation was not successful.

2.Unable to authenticate the package:727047181.itmsp

3.ERROR ITMS -9000:"The bundle identifier cannot be changed from the current val;ue,'com.redim.pokerastic'. If u want to change your bundle identifier,you will need to create a new application in itunes Connect."at softwareAssests/SoftwareAsset(MZItmspsoftwareAssetPackage)

Please any one help me out dis problem.

Comment: Looks like you've tried to change the app bundle identifier; perhaps accidentally...

Comment: is it really called "pokerastic"; I would have thought "pokertastic" to be so much better...

Answer (score 2):

This has happened to me a lot of times. To fix it, you should first delete your previous provisioning profiles for your application, then go to [developer.apple.com](https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/profile/profileList.action) and create a new provisioning profile for App Store

Then, choose the correct bundle ID (try to not use a wildcard ID) and choose the certificate that you would like to include in your profile. Make sure that your provisioning profile is named your app name (`pokerastic`) instead of `com.redim.pokerastic`, then download it and open it.

If you do not have any certificates, go to [developer.apple.com](https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/certificate/certificateList.action) and click the plus sign to add a new certificate.

Choose App store and Ad hoc then do exactly what it says to do. Make your certificate, upload it to Apple, then open up the download that Apple gives you.

In [iTunesConnect](http://itunesconnect.apple.com), make sure that the bundle IDs of your applications match. You can find this by clicking manage applications, then clicking on the app you would like to upload, and in the top left it should say the bundle ID.

Finally, in Xcode under your application manager, click the target app then click 'General' at the top. Make sure that the bundle ID is the same as the one on iTunes Connect, then make sure the versions are the same.

The error it gives you states that your bundle IDs do not match, so make sure that they do. If you want to change it, you're going to have to go to iTunesConnect and create a new application with the same bundle ID that you have in Xcode. Make sure the one on iTunesConnect has the bundle ID `com.redim.pokerastic`