# Xcode Upload Binary Apple's Web Service Operation Was Not Successful

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect

I am trying to upload a new binary for an existing app.  I archive it in Xcode, then click Distribute from the organizer window.  I connect, it shows the apps that are waiting for upload, I select the correct one and click next.  This is where it keeps messing up at.  After it sits for a while at uploading I get

Apple's web service operation was not successful
Unable to authenticate the package
There is also an error about an icon file referenced in CFBundleIcons not being found, despite the fact that I removed the old icon file from the plist cleaned it, and submitted again.

Comment: Visit this link for solution. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19827357/xcode5-apples-web-service-operation-was-not-successful/21330553#21330553

Answer (score 0):

possible solutions:

1. did you change your password? try to log out and log in again. 
   see this Apple Support Communities entry: [Unable to authenticate the package](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3033099?start=15&tstart=0)
2. is there a typo in your info.plist? see this stackoverflow entry: [Unable to authenticate the package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19324505/unable-to-authenticate-the-package-721772200-itmsp)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, doesn't worked neither even using the asset catalog for the icon. It was because despite of using it, at the same time a had a couple lines at my Info.plist indicating the names of the icons CFBundleIcons/Icon files, for example. After a lot of pain trying to find what was wrong, removing this lines worked for me.