# XCode says "missing recommended icon file" even though it's there

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, app-store

I am using Organizer to "Validate" under the "Archives" tab getting ready for App Store submission.

It tells me that I am missing the 120x120 icon, but I am clearly not.  I'm stuck.

When I look at the image catalog, I can confirm that the iPhone App iOS 7 60pt file is present.

Any gotchas I'm overlooking?

Here's an image of my settings: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2UL8p.png

Comment: Exact message: Missing recommended icon file - The bundle does not contain an app icon for iPhone / iPod Touch of exactly '120x120' pixels, in .png format.

Comment: Take a look at this answer.It might have what you need. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18736954/missing-recommended-icon-file-the-bundle-does-not-contain-an-app-icon-for-iph

Comment: Thanks @akash - I did follow that answer, everything is there.

Comment: try deleting(optional) and re-adding the icon file..

Comment: @akash - I tried that.  Also tried restarting XCode.  Still get the message.

Comment: Can you post a link to screenshot.. i see u don’t have enough rep to post image here..

Comment: try to delete the icon ,search for the name of the icon maybe there is a duplicate , clean , add image again , then archive ..

Comment: @akash - Posted link in original message

Comment: @M.Othman - Tried that.  Also just migrated to an asset catalog.  Still no good.

Comment: Try naming the icon Icon@2x~iphone.png For some reason I got this name automatically form XCode once and stuck to it and it has always worked for me.

Comment: This is 8 months old but for anyone reading this with the same problem…after adding the correct icons remember to delete the archive and create a new one before attempting validation again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if your info.plist file has Icon files property list like shown below.. and matches with icon file names..

[image]

[image]

Comment: why there are two naming conventions. you are using @2x and icon-50 like two formats. try making it like shown in my image. I’m pretty sure it should work..

Comment: change icon names and add to the project.. update .plist and update the Appicons paths..

Comment: Thanks @akash - your example doesn't include the new 120x120 and 60x60 icons for iOS7.  I'm still having issues.

Comment: @chrysb because its iPad app example. in my example iOS 7 iPad has 76*76 and 152*152 dimensions. which in your case will be 60*60 and 120*120..