# Xcode 5.02 Photoshop icon creation

Tags: ios, xcode, photoshop-script

I am currently trying to push an app to the store (Build > Archive), but it keeps complaining about sizes of icons and certain sizes not actually existing.

[image]

I cannot find a slot in the Images.xcassets > App icon for a 120 or a 152, so first where do I put these icons so that it builds correctly.

[image]

Secondly, this is ridiculous, is there a photoshop script I can use that does the same icon up in 120, 152, and whatever other sizes it needs.

Comment: 2*60 = 120 and 2*76 = 152 (its shown "x2" since iOS7 devices use Retina except iPad Mini).

Comment: who -1'd without a comment.

Comment: Xcode 5.2 isn’t a thing (yet). Did you mean 5.0.2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have modified an old photoshop script to create icons that have a size that matches the requirements in xcode 5.2

https://gist.github.com/derpest/8437300

Adding the correct icon to the correct place stops the errors upon validating to push to store.

A good explanation of this is explained here: ['Missing recommended icon file - The bundle does not contain an app icon for iPhone / iPod Touch of exactly '120x120' pixels, in .png format'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18736954/missing-recommended-icon-file-the-bundle-does-not-contain-an-app-icon-for-iph)

Answer (score 3):

App script for photoshop

http://www.appsbynight.com/2012/09/17/create-every-ios-icon-for-your-app-with-a-photoshop-script/

Not used it, as I have a program on the Mac that converts it for me from a large image to smaller ones.. see below and is free...

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/prepo/id476533227?mt=12

also the images to have @2x for the larger ons 
so
icon-60.png
icon-60@2x.png   (120 sized one)

Comment: yea i found that and modded it... thought I Would leave the question here so other people could find it - looks like it is getting a few -1's though

Answer (score 1):

This is not ridiculous. 
2*60 = 120
2*76 = 152
Note that's said in "points" and not pixels. You have to check for the coefficient (x2 for Retina Display). Plus, since in iOS7 sizes changed, all iPhone/iPod Touch which can have iOS7 are Retina (that's why there is only the "x2" for iOS7 iPhone). For iPad, there is iPad Mini (non-retina).

Comment: Its ridiculous to have to create 10 different icons without a built in tool, also I have added the 152px images with the same errors.

Comment: Also, I asked about a photoshop script, I found one bit it is a little outdated.

Answer (score 0):

If you want an automated way to make your icons at all the right sizes, check out the [App Icon Template](http://appicontemplate.com). It’s a Photoshop file and a companion action that let you design your icon once, then export it all at once. Be warned that you may want to tweak your icons at each individual size to get the best look, but this is a good starting point because it lets you quickly preview your icon at all sizes.