# Phonegap app submission to AppStore - ITMS-9000 error

Tags: iphone, cordova, app-store

On attempting to submit my Phonegap app to the Appstore I get the following error

ERROR ITMS-9000: "Your binary is not optimized for iPhone 5 - New iPhone apps and app updates submitted targeting iOS 6 and above must support the 4-inch display on iPhone 5 and must include a launch image with the -568h size modifier immediately following the &lt;basename&gt; portion of the launch image's filename. Launch images must be PNG files and located at the top-level of your bundle, or provided within each .lproj folder if you localize your launch images.

I have the following splash images specified in my Phonegap config.xml

```
<gap:splash src="images/splash320x480.png" width="320" height="480" />
<gap:splash src="images/splash640x960.png" width="640" height="960" />
<gap:splash src="images/splash1024x768.png" width="1024" height="768" />
<gap:splash src="images/splash768x1024.png" width="768" height="1024" />
<gap:splash src="images/splash1024x748.png" width="1024" height="748" />
<gap:splash src="images/splash1024x748.png" width="1024" height="748" />
<gap:splash src="images/splash1496x2048.png" width="1496" height="2048" />
<gap:splash src="images/splash768x1004.png" width="768" height="1004" />
<gap:splash src="images/splash1536x2008.png" width="1536" height="2008" />p
<gap:splash src="images/splash2048x1536.png" width="2048" height="1536" />
<gap:splash src="images/splash1536x2048.png" width="1536" height="2048" />
<gap:splash src="images/splash_retina_640x1136.png" width="640" height="1136" />
<gap:splash src="images/splash_retina_640x960.png" width="640" height="960" />
<gap:splash src="images/splash640x1136.png" width="640" height="1136" />
```

Can anyone point me in the direction of what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You can open Xcode project file which is generated by phone gap and check there if it assigned correct launch images or not.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18736954/missing-recommended-icon-file-the-bundle-does-not-contain-an-app-icon-for-iph. It contains new UI requirements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to add proper splash screen images for supporting 4.0 inch devices.
Naming convention for splash screen.
Default.png for non-retina 3.5" devices.
Default@2x.png for retina 3.5" devices.
Default-568h@2x.png for retina 4.0" devices.

Answer (score 1):

Default-568h@2x.png (640x1136px) – "iPhone Portrait iOS5,6 – Retina 4" and "iPhone Portrait iOS7,8 – Retina 4"

You can find any other splash screen sizes here:
http://www.ios-developer.net/iphone-ipad-programmer/icons_and_graphics/default-image