# phonegap Error uploading app :Your binary is not optimized for iPhone 5

Tags: cordova, configure, phonegap-build

i try to upload my phonegap app(.ipa file) using application loader but it gives below error

```
          ERROR ITMS-9000: "Your binary is not optimized for iPhone 5 -
     New iPhone apps and app updates submitted must support the 
    4-inch display on iPhone 5 and must include a launch 
    image with the -568h size modifier immediately following the
     &amp;lt;basename&amp;gt; portion of the launch image's filename.
     Launch images must be PNG files and located at the top-level of 
your bundle, or provided within each .lproj folder if you localize
 your launch images. Learn more about iPhone 5 support and app launch
 images by reviewing the 'iOS Human Interface Guidelines' at 'https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience
/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconsImages/IconsImages.html#//apple_ref
/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH14-SW5' and the 'iOS App Programming Guide' at 
'https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual
/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/App-RelatedResources/App-RelatedResources.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH6-SW12'." at SoftwareAssets/SoftwareAsset (MZItmspSoftwareAssetPackage)
```

i referenced many sampled but in all samples it give same error
i used [phonegap document](http://phonegap.com/blog/build/new-apple-app-store-submittal-rules/) it still give same error

this is my config.xml

```
    <icon src="icon.png" />
    <icon src="icon@2x.png" />
   <icon src="Icon-Small.png" />
   <icon src="Icon-Small@2x.png" />  
   <icon src="Default.png" />
   <icon src="Default@2x.png" />   
    <icon src="icon-568h@2x.png" />   
    <icon src="icons/ios/57.png"            gap:platform="ios"       
 width="57" height="57" />
    <icon src="72.png"            gap:platform="ios"        
width="72" height="72" />
    <icon src="72@2x.png" /> 
    <icon src="icons/ios/57-2x.png"         gap:platform="ios"       
 width="114" height="114" />
    <icon src="icons/ios/72-2x.png"         gap:platform="ios"        
width="144" height="144" />
 <icon src="Icon-Small-50.png" />
    <icon src="Icon-Small-50@2x.png" />
  <icon src="Default-Landscape.png" />
    <icon src="Default-Landscape@2x.png" />
  <icon src="Default-Portrait.png" />
    <icon src="Default-Portrait@2x.png" />
  <icon src="Icon-40.png" />
    <icon src="Icon-40@2x.png" /> 
 <icon src="Icon-60.png" />
    <icon src="Icon-60@2x.png" /> 

 <icon src="Icon-76.png" />
    <icon src="Icon-76@2x.png" /> 
   <!-- Define app splash screen for each platform. -->
    <gap:splash src="splashScreen.png"  />
    <gap:splash src="icons/ios/screen-iphone-portrait.png"    gap:platform="ios" 
    width="320" height="480" />
    <gap:splash src="icons/ios/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-2x.png" gap:platform="ios" 
    width="640" height="960" />
    <gap:splash src="icons/ios/ios/screen-ipad-portrait.png"      gap:platform="ios"
     width="768" height="1024" />
    <gap:splash src="icons/ios/ios/screen-ipad-landscape.png"     gap:platform="ios" 
    width="1024" height="768" />
```

Comment: Have you found a solution? I'm going throught the same error

Comment: with that icons it work for me:http://yazilimsozluk.com/phonegap-ios-uygulama-ikonlari

Comment: possible duplicate of [Phonegap app submission to AppStore - ITMS-9000 error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21456317/phonegap-app-submission-to-appstore-itms-9000-error)

Comment: this needs duplicates since ios dev is so so bad

Answer (score 8):

It seems like we were missing some splash screens. Your app should have the following on config:

```
<gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait.png"          gap:platform="ios"     width="320" height="480" />
  <gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-2x.png"       gap:platform="ios"     width="640" height="960" />
  <gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-landscape.png"         gap:platform="ios"     width="480" height="320" />
  <gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-landscape-2x.png"      gap:platform="ios"     width="960" height="640" />
  <gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-portrait.png"            gap:platform="ios"     width="768" height="1024" />
  <gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-portrait-2x.png"         gap:platform="ios"     width="1536" height="2008" />
  <gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-landscape.png"           gap:platform="ios"     width="1024" height="768" />
  <gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-landscape-2x.png"        gap:platform="ios"     width="2048" height="1496" />
  <gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-568h-2x.png"  gap:platform="ios"     width="640"  height="1136" />
```

Put those files on your project and it will work.

Comment: with that icons it work for me:http://yazilimsozluk.com/phonegap-ios-uygulama-ikonlari

Answer (score 3):

Is necessary load all icons and screens

```
<icon src="icon.png" gap:platform="ios" width="57" height="57" />
<icon src="icon-60.png" gap:platform="ios" width="60" height="60" />
<icon src="icon-60@2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="120" height="120" />
<icon src="icon@2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="114" height="114" />
<!-- iPad -->
<icon src="icon-72.png" gap:platform="ios" width="72" height="72" />
<icon src="icon-72@2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="144" height="144" />
<icon src="icon-76.png" gap:platform="ios" width="76" height="76" />
<icon src="icon-76@2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="152" height="152" />

<!-- Settings Icon -->
<icon src="icon-small.png" gap:platform="ios" width="29" height="29" />
<icon src="icon-small@2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="58" height="58" />
<icon src="icon-50.png" gap:platform="ios" width="50" height="50" />
<icon src="icon-50@2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="100" height="100" />

<!-- Spotlight Icon -->
<icon src="icon-40.png" gap:platform="ios" width="40" height="40" />
<icon src="icon-40@2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="80" height="80" />
<!-- Define app splash screen for each platform. -->
<!-- iPhone and iPod touch -->
<gap:splash src="Default.png" gap:platform="ios" width="320" height="480" />
<gap:splash src="Default@2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="640" height="960" />

<!-- iPhone 5 / iPod Touch (5th Generation) -->
<gap:splash src="Default-568h@2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="640" height="1136" />

<!-- iPad -->
<gap:splash src="Default-Portrait.png" gap:platform="ios" width="768" height="1024" />
<gap:splash src="Default-Landscape.png" gap:platform="ios" width="1024" height="768" />

<!-- Retina iPad -->
<gap:splash src="Default-Portrait@2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="1536" height="2048" />
<gap:splash src="Default-Landscape@2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="2048" height="1536" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the above responses helped me, here my complete list for Icons & Splash Screen

```
<!-- iPhone -->
<icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-57.png"            gap:platform="ios"      width="57" height="57" />
<icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-57-2x.png"         gap:platform="ios"      width="114" height="114" />
<icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-60.png"            gap:platform="ios"      width="60" height="60" />
<icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-60-2x.png"         gap:platform="ios"      width="120" height="120" />

<!-- iPad -->
<icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-72.png"            gap:platform="ios"      width="72" height="72" />
<icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-72-2x.png"         gap:platform="ios"      width="144" height="144" />
<icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-76.png"            gap:platform="ios"      width="76" height="76" />
<icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-76-2x.png"         gap:platform="ios"      width="152" height="152" />

<!-- Settings Icon -->
<icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-small.png"         gap:platform="ios"      width="29" height="29" />
<icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-small-2x.png"      gap:platform="ios"      width="58" height="58" />
<icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-50.png"            gap:platform="ios"      width="50" height="50" />
<icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-50@2x.png"         gap:platform="ios"      width="100" height="100" />

<!-- Spotlight Icon -->
<icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-40.png"            gap:platform="ios"      width="40" height="40" />
<icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-40@2x.png"         gap:platform="ios"      width="80" height="80" />

<!-- WebOs -->
<icon src="res/icon/webos/icon-64.png"          gap:platform="webos" />

<!-- Windows -->
<icon src="res/icon/windows-phone/icon-48.png"  gap:platform="winphone" />
<icon src="res/icon/windows-phone/icon-173.png" gap:platform="winphone"   gap:role="background" />

<!-- Define app splash screen for each platform. -->
<!-- iPad -->
<gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-landscape.png"          gap:platform="ios"     width="1024" height="768" />
<gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-landscape-2x.png"       gap:platform="ios"     width="2048" height="1496" />
<gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-portrait.png"           gap:platform="ios"     width="768" height="1024" />
<gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-portrait-2x.png"        gap:platform="ios"     width="1536" height="2008" />

<!-- iPhone -->
<gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-landscape.png"         gap:platform="ios"     width="480" height="320" />
<gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-landscape-2x.png"      gap:platform="ios"     width="960" height="640" />
<gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait.png"          gap:platform="ios"     width="320" height="480" />
<gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-2x.png"       gap:platform="ios"     width="640" height="960" />
<gap:splash src="res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-568h-2x.png"  gap:platform="ios"     width="640"  height="1136" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I searched for days to find an answer to this same problem. My solution was the file format. **You can only use PNG.** File name and path do not matter. I was using JPG's and it kept throwing the same error when I tried to upload my binary, as soon as I switched to PNG's it worked perfectly.

Here is all icon and splash/launch sizes if anyone wants a quick copy and paste.

```
<icon src="tools/images/icons/36.png"   gap:platform="android"      gap:qualifier="ldpi" />
<icon src="tools/images/icons/48.png"   gap:platform="android"      gap:qualifier="mdpi" />
<icon src="tools/images/icons/72.png"   gap:platform="android"      gap:qualifier="hdpi" />
<icon src="tools/images/icons/96.png"   gap:platform="android"      gap:qualifier="xhdpi" />
<icon src="tools/images/icons/29.png"   gap:platform="ios"          width="29" height="29" />
<icon src="tools/images/icons/40.png"   gap:platform="ios"          width="40" height="40" />
<icon src="tools/images/icons/50.png"   gap:platform="ios"          width="50" height="50" />
<icon src="tools/images/icons/57.png"   gap:platform="ios"          width="57" height="57" />
<icon src="tools/images/icons/58.png"   gap:platform="ios"          width="58" height="58" />
<icon src="tools/images/icons/60.png"   gap:platform="ios"          width="60" height="60" />
<icon src="tools/images/icons/72.png"   gap:platform="ios"          width="72" height="72" />
<icon src="tools/images/icons/76.png"   gap:platform="ios"          width="76" height="76" />
<icon src="tools/images/icons/80.png"   gap:platform="ios"          width="80" height="80" />
<icon src="tools/images/icons/100.png"  gap:platform="ios"          width="100" height="100" />
<icon src="tools/images/icons/114.png"  gap:platform="ios"          width="114" height="114" />
<icon src="tools/images/icons/120.png"  gap:platform="ios"          width="120" height="120" />
<icon src="tools/images/icons/144.png"  gap:platform="ios"          width="144" height="144" />
<icon src="tools/images/icons/152.png"  gap:platform="ios"          width="152" height="152" />
<icon src="tools/images/icons/64.png"   gap:platform="webos" />
<icon src="tools/images/icons/48.png"   gap:platform="winphone" />
<icon src="tools/images/icons/173.png"  gap:platform="winphone"     gap:role="background" />



<!-- Define app splash screen for each platform.    -->
<gap:splash src="tools/images/splash/android/320x426.9.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="ldpi" />
<gap:splash src="tools/images/splash/android/320x470.9.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="mdpi" />
<gap:splash src="tools/images/splash/android/480x640.9.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="hdpi" />
<gap:splash src="tools/images/splash/android/720x960.9.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="xhdpi" />
<gap:splash src="tools/images/splash/ios/320x480.png"       gap:platform="ios"     width="320" height="480" />
<gap:splash src="tools/images/splash/ios/640x960.png"       gap:platform="ios"     width="640" height="960" />
<gap:splash src="tools/images/splash/ios/640x1136.png"      gap:platform="ios"     width="640" height="1136" />
<gap:splash src="tools/images/splash/ios/768x1024.png"      gap:platform="ios"     width="768" height="1024" />
<gap:splash src="tools/images/splash/ios/1024x768.png"      gap:platform="ios"     width="1024" height="768" />
<gap:splash src="tools/images/splash/ios/1536x2008.png"     gap:platform="ios"     width="1536" height="2008" />
<gap:splash src="tools/images/splash/ios/1536x2048.png"     gap:platform="ios"     width="1536" height="2048" />
<gap:splash src="tools/images/splash/ios/2048x1496.png"     gap:platform="ios"     width="2048" height="1496" />
<gap:splash src="tools/images/splash/ios/2048x1536.png"     gap:platform="ios"     width="2048" height="1536" />
<gap:splash src="tools/images/splash/ios/320x480.png"       gap:platform="winphone" />
```

**Again, only file type matters.** File path and file name do not; phonegap build renames everything anyway.

Comment: There isn't a single non-png in the question; every image is a PNG.

Answer (score 0):

i fixed that 
there is all needed icons
[here](http://yazilimsozluk.com/phonegap-ios-uygulama-ikonlari)

i resubmit all apps
here is link

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/english-words-memory-game/id907071052?l=tr&ls=1&mt=8

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/243/id896701562?l=tr&ls=1&mt=8

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.hybridsoftware.game

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.hybridsoftware.synonymsmemorygame