# Is Asset Catalog mandatory in Xcode 5 for app store approval

Tags: iphone, ios7, xcode5

i am updating my X code 4.6 build to X code 5 . i have made all the necessary changes but i have not used assets catalog for App icons because X code 5 has automatically found icons in `App Kind` section.
So i have only one query that if i do not `Use Asset Catalog` will my app be rejected .. ?

i have followed this link ['Missing recommended icon file - The bundle does not contain an app icon for iPhone / iPod Touch of exactly '120x120' pixels, in .png format'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18736954/missing-recommended-icon-file-the-bundle-does-not-contain-an-app-icon-for-iph)

and searched everywhere but no one has said about using Asset Catalog as mandatory.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

You can still set your icons the old fashioned way if you wish.  But Asset Catalogs tend to be easier and simpler to deal with.

Also, it is not necessary to include all of the images in an Asset Catalog.  One of my recent apps I sent in, I didn't fill out all of the images (I was in a hurry and didn't want to go back export different sized images if I didn't need to).  I got a warning that was presented to me in many different forms like an email and a mark on the submitted archive in the Xcode Organizer.  But the update went through.  It is recommended that you fill out the catalog completely but not strictly required.

Comment: Perfect response: it is not necessary, but recommended to avoid errors rendering images.

Comment: Thanks WolfLink . it helped a lot .