# XCode5 won't accept all my icons and launch images

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode5

After switching to XCode5 I've just re-done all my icons and launch images for an app, with the exception of retina launch images I should have a complete set for both iPad and iPhone, iOS6 and iOS7, thanks to this tool: http://www.appiconsizes.com/

But XCode5 absolutely refuses to use them all. I removed all the old images from my project and added the new ones. Some, XCode automatically detects, seemingly at random. Many others, it says it can't find the images needed even though they are named according to Apple's guidelines (as far as I can see, it's all a bit confusing with so many variants). It lets me find them manually but doesn't seem to be using them properly.

And my launch images, it insists on using images from a different target even though these are definitely *not* marked to be included in this target. It won't even let me change those ones, if I try to then it just ignores my selection.

A few screenshots follow. I originally had just an "Icon" icon identifier in my plist, since Apple say it will automatically detect different variants, but XCode has then added Icon-76 and Icon-120, seemingly contradicting this. I'm aware XCode5 supports controlling things more through your plist than XCode4, but shouldn't require that - you should be able to tell it the icon base name or use "default" and it would figure things out?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Yeah, nice question: the always-evolving approach to different screen sizes & resolutions within Xcode is quite aggravating. Are you using an Asset Catalog (which I haven't totally figured out yet, myself) for this?

Comment: No, this was preoviously an XCode 4.6 project; I opened it in XCode5, updated the new images, and tried to test it.

Comment: Have you checked the sizes of the included images? Still, there seem to be a couple of images missing.

Comment: As I said, a couple are missing, mainly retina. But all the ones with -xxx are definitely the right sizes and these are not all being picked up.

Comment: May it help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18736954/missing-recommended-icon-file-the-bundle-does-not-contain-an-app-icon-for-iph/18737063#18737063

Answer (score 1):

Use an asset catalog for your project.

It has placeholders for the launch image and the icon and each one tells you which size it needs.

Much easier than handling lots of dirrefent files in different locations.

In the project info page there is a button that says "use asset catalog". It will import all your images for you. The code doesn't change when using an asset catalog so it will all still work.

Another thing with asset catalog is that the name of the files doesn't matter. You just drag the image to the slot you want it to go into. With icons and stuff there is only a size restriction.

Even for retina images you don't need the @2x before because there is now a slot for "standard" and "retina" images.

Comment: Will an asset catalog allow me to set iOS6 images as well as iOS7 ones? I need to retain compatibility because my target audience (business, medical) is a bit conservative with having the newest versions.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is in Your icon Name,

for iPhone retina Name should be **Icon-60.png , Icon-60@2x.png**

So as Fogmeister suggested use asset catalog
Like

[image]

So its like

[image]