# What is the app icon size in ios7 for both iPhone an iPad?

Tags: ios

Does anyone know how I should name this 120 X 120 icon for iOS 7 and my old iOS 6 icon that was 114 X 114?

Comment: http://blog.manbolo.com/2013/08/15/new-metrics-for-ios-7-app-icons and  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18736954/missing-recommended-icon-file-the-bundle-does-not-contain-an-app-icon-for-iph/18737063#18737063

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have a 1024x1024 icon file, then its better to use [iConify](https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/iconify/id416289784?mt=12) software.
you can download it from app store.

in it, you will get all icons size for ios 6, ios 7 and for both (iPhone & iPad).

you just need to drag the 1024x1024 icon in that software.

make sure that your file name is icon.png (resolution 1024x1024).

and this software also use for convert ratina image to 1x and 2x iamges. with proper name like (xxx@2x.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [MakeAppIcon](http://makeappicon.com/) for convert 1024*1024 size icon image to all size of icon. It will provide you all icons iOS version vise.

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to drag the image in Xcode 5 it will automatically rename it.
Else you can name it as **icon@2x.png**
or **logo@2x.png**

You need the following app icon to add a **120x120** high resolution icon. Now, if you want to target only **iOS 7**, you just need **76 x 76, 120 x 120** and **152 x 152** icon sizes. If you also want to target **iOS 6**, you’ll need **57 x 57, 72 x 72, 76 x 76, 114 x 114, 120 x 120, 144 x 144 and 152 x 152 icon sizes**. Without counting Spotlight and Settings icon if you don’t want the OS to interpolate them

Comment: You need the following app icon to add a 120x120 high resolution icon. Now, if you want to target only iOS 7, you just need 76 x 76, 120 x 120 and 152 x 152 icon sizes. If you also want to target iOS 6, you’ll need 57 x 57, 72 x 72, 76 x 76, 114 x 114, 120 x 120, 144 x 144 and 152 x 152 icon sizes. Without counting Spotlight and Settings icon if you don’t want the OS to interpolate them!