# Missing recommended icon file in xcode6

Tags: ios, xcode6

I've already configured all required icons in xcode6, unfortunately when to validate in Xcode6 then encounter following error

> Missing recommended icon file - The bundle does not contain an app
>   icon for iPhone / iPod Touch of exactly '120x120' pixels, in .png
>   format

following question and answers showed that how to solve such kind of error but I have not found the point yet. Attach is my app icon and configuration.

[image]

Comment: see if it works in your case
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18736954/missing-recommended-icon-file-the-bundle-does-not-contain-an-app-icon-for-iph

Comment: that's what I mention above. I have not found any solutions there.

Comment: Once try with xcode 6.0.1

Comment: not yet. it can be concerned?

Answer (score 0):

By reading the error message, it looks like your image file is not exactly the required size for an icon. Have you checked it? Your image file must have the exact size requirement.

Comment: All are required size including 120x120 in these images but got error whenever validation by Xcode.