# Missing required icon file. The bundle does not contain

Tags: ios, iphone

This is the error message:

> ITunes Store operation failed. Missing required icon file. The bundle
>   does not contain an app icon for iPhone / iPod Touch of exactly
>   "120x120" pixels, in .png format for iOS versions >= 7.0.

**I have this problem while submitting my app to the app store, I face this problem while validating my project and I tried all the answers here in stackoverflow but the error is same .**

Comment: *Does* your bundle contain an app icon as described?

Comment: it will be better to post the screenshot of xcasset of icon

Comment: possible duplicate of ['Missing recommended icon file - The bundle does not contain an app icon for iPhone / iPod Touch of exactly '120x120' pixels, in .png format'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18736954/missing-recommended-icon-file-the-bundle-does-not-contain-an-app-icon-for-iph)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Open your project's General Preferences in Xcode, and make sure that your App Icons Source is the Asset Catalog named "AppIcon":

[image: App Icons and Launch Images]

Then, in the project navigator, click Images.xcassets, click AppIcon, and then drag and drop your icons into the required places. If AppIcon is not shown, you'll have to right click and choose "New App Icon" and then select the proper icons from the inspector on the right:

[image: AppIcon in Images.xcassets]

Once you've done this, your icons should show up where they're supposed to.

Comment: yes maybe that was the problem and my icons folder name was AppIcon-1, and I changed it to AppIcon and changed App Icon Source to AppIcon.

Comment: Glad everything works now! If this answer was the correct one, please click the check to mark it as correct!

Comment: Another important note (esp for ionic users), MAKE SURE that you click through EACH and every image to make sure the size of the actual image matches the size of the role it's assigned to. If not, Apple will give you some archaic answer that will make your life miserable.

Comment: @Jacksonkr I have added an icon of size 60x60 but when I click on that it shows 20x20 on right side!

Comment: @ZeeshanAhmadKhalil Did you assign your 60x60 to a 3x slot? If so then your image needs to be 3 times the size it asks for eg 60x60 in a 3x slot becomes 20x20 for a 3x device while a 180x180 at 3x becomes 60x60. If you're not sure then playing around with image sizes is a good way to trial & error it out.

Comment: @Jacksonkr I got it now, this wasn't the issue the issue was with icon names.

Comment: I followed the exact same steps. Drag&Drop works fine and all icons are where they belong to but (1) the small favicon is still showng the placeholder icon and (2) on Appstore Connect Upload Apple gives me an error that the 120px image is missing.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on AppIcon xcassets, then you can see new app Icon.

It will show you New App Icon, then it will show you all required icon, and you need to fill everything needed there and remove current one.

Answer (score 0):

Please change your development target 6.0 to 7.0  in your xcode and start new archive its working successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Just had same problem and post answer in case someone like me, stumbles over here. Using Xcode 8.3.3 and wanted to use AppIcon in Assets catalogue. Tried all sorts of Stack Overflow answers without success.

Finally learned about a deep clean step from Ken/Apple Forum:

- removed all icon files, whether from resources (delete - trash) or appicon file (select - remove selected items); removed even assets folder
- deep cleaned (Use the Product menu w/option key pressed, then choose to 'clean build folder')
- added a new asset catalogue and called it "Assets" right clicked in Assets folder and added new app icon set - changed that one in inspector to be for iOS >=7
- triple checked all my icon files OUTSIDE of Xcode (all were already png files of right resolution, but some had still colour profile attached from photoshop elements or did have indexed colour instead of RGB profile. so I made sure I only save a png file without colour profile and from a background layer) - not sure that was necessary
- archived the build from Product menu
- validated and uploaded the build from Window - Organizer

Answer (score 0):

I was facing this error while uploading app to AppStore

> Missing required icon file - The bundle does not contain an app icon
>   for iPad of exactly ‘76x76’ pixels, in .png format for iOS versions >=
>   7.0.
>
> Missing required icon file - The bundle does not contain an app icon
>   for iPad of exactly ‘152x152’ pixels, in .png format for iOS versions
>   = 7.0.

I solved it by adding this script at the end of **`Podfile`**

```
post_install do |installer|
    copy_pods_resources_path = "Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-TargetName/Pods-TargetName-resources.sh"
    string_to_replace = '--compile "${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${UNLOCALIZED_RESOURCES_FOLDER_PATH}"'
    assets_compile_with_app_icon_arguments = '--compile "${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${UNLOCALIZED_RESOURCES_FOLDER_PATH}" --app-icon "${ASSETCATALOG_COMPILER_APPICON_NAME}" --output-partial-info-plist "${BUILD_DIR}/assetcatalog_generated_info.plist"'
    text = File.read(copy_pods_resources_path)
    new_contents = text.gsub(string_to_replace, assets_compile_with_app_icon_arguments)
    File.open(copy_pods_resources_path, "w") {|file| file.puts new_contents }
end
```

Install your **`Podfile`** again, may it should help.

> P.S. *Remember* **`TargetName`** in above script should be your Projects'
>   Target Name. e.g. if your target name is `MyAppName` then you should
>   replace **`TargetName`** in above script as `MyAppName`