# Missing required icon file. Bundle does not contain 120x120. Using Asset Catalog

Tags: ios, icons

When submitting my app to the app store I get the following error:

```
ERROR ITMS-9022:"Missing required icon file. The bundle does not contain an app icon for iPhone/iPod Touch of exactly '120x120' pixels in .png format for iOS versions >= 7.0"
```

I'm using an asset catalog and it does contain this icon.  See screenshot.  I was using files in a previous release (instead of the asset catalog), but I deleted the icon.png files from the Images folder and I changed the General settings to use the Asset Catalog instead of the files. 
[image]

I've followed the steps in this answer, but still no luck :

[Missing required icon file. The bundle does not contain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29501830/missing-required-icon-file-the-bundle-does-not-contain)

[image]

After updated the icons I did clean and build.  I cannot figure it out!  Using XCode V 7.1

Comment: check this link helps with you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18736954/missing-recommended-icon-file-the-bundle-does-not-contain-an-app-icon-for-iph

Comment: Can you please know me that have add @2x file for 60pt and same as 3x

Answer (score 0):

I did not properly migrate from using files to using the asset catalog.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-image_catalog-1.0/chapters/StoringAppIconsandLaunchImagesinanAssetCatalog.html