# Why to add icons in info.plist file?

Tags: ios, xcode

I have added required icons files in my app. But when I upload app to app store then it shows me an error saying **Bundle does not contain icon file 57*57** but in my app I already have it.

I developed this app in Xcode 5 then that time I added icons in info.plist because on some of devices icons were not visible.

```
<dict>
        <key>CFBundlePrimaryIcon</key>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleIconFiles</key>
            <array>
                <string>icon76</string>
                <string>icon40</string>
                <string>icon40@2x</string>
                <string>icon60@2x</string>
                <string>icon40@3x</string>
                <string>icon50@2x</string>
                <string>icon50</string>
            </array>
            <key>UIPrerenderedIcon</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
```

So why do we add icons in plist because in my latest project in xcode 7 I did not add icon name in plist still it was uploaded on app store.

**UPDATE**

```
 <key>CFBundleIcons</key>
    <dict/>
    <key>CFBundleIcons~ipad</key>
    <dict/>
```

used above code in plist & tried to run it does not show any icon

Comment: Why are you not using Asset Catalogs?

Comment: grow up now just use aseest for setting icon visit my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18736954/missing-recommended-icon-file-the-bundle-does-not-contain-an-app-icon-for-iph/18737063#18737063 and i dont found any 57x57 in your plist

Comment: i have grown up bro.read my question twice i am having a doubt & issue with uploading app

Comment: i have read aseest is easy to set icon and that no need to set plist thing and also in your pilist there is no any image that have 57x57 px image

Comment: use Asset catalog under app icons and launch images in project target

Comment: That is what i am saying.I have added icons in images.xcassets & when i remove icons names from plist file then it does not show icons on device that i issue i have

Comment: remove icons filed from plist and just use images.xcasset and update your Xcode you are using very old one

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1686/_index.html, use this link to name your icons.

Answer (score 0):

Use Image Assets and fill up all icons with respective size and resolutions.
In turn it automatically gets added to the pList, as Xcode does this part itself, just like when you add URL schemes in project settings, all those URL gets added in plist by XCode itself.
While uploading to Appstore, they check the plist info.

Answer (score -1):

follow these steps it helps you

- Select Project target.
- Choose app icons and source image > select AppIcon > then click on arrow button

[image]

- An empty app icon set is created, with an image well for each image representation in the set.

Drag an app icon from the Finder to the appropriate image well in the set viewer.