# How to fix App Store Connect Operation Error In XCode V 12.0-Compatible

Tags: android, ios, swift, xcode, react-native

I am quite new deploying my work to the app store, What I did I read some articles how to deploy IOS project, and watch some youtube tutorial, I just continue learning and try the best to push my work to the app store, however I have alot of error I encounter in the distributing process almost 2day still fixing on this bug, I can't find any resources to fix on this bugs.

Errors:

> App Store Connect Operation Error
> ERROR ITMS-90713: "Missing Info.plist value. A value for the Info.plist key 'CFBundleIconName' is missing in the bundle 'com.smt.isn'. Apps built with iOS 11 or later SDK must supply app icons in an asset catalog and must also provide a value for this Info.plist key. For more information see [http://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/current/#/dev10510b1f7."](http://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/current/#/dev10510b1f7.%22)

> App Store Connect Operation Error
> ERROR ITMS-90022: "Missing required icon file. The bundle does not contain an app icon for iPhone / iPod Touch of exactly '120x120' pixels, in .png format for iOS versions >= 10.0. To support older versions of iOS, the icon may be required in the bundle outside of an asset catalog. Make sure the Info.plist file includes appropriate entries referencing the file. See [https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/user_interface"](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/user_interface%22)

> App Store Connect Operation Error
> ERROR ITMS-90023: "Missing required icon file. The bundle does not contain an app icon for iPad of exactly '167x167' pixels, in .png format for iOS versions supporting iPad Pro. To support older operating systems, the icon may be required in the bundle outside of an asset catalog. Make sure the Info.plist file includes appropriate entries referencing the file. See [https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/user_interface"](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/user_interface%22)

> App Store Connect Operation Error
> ERROR ITMS-90023: "Missing required icon file. The bundle does not contain an app icon for iPad of exactly '152x152' pixels, in .png format for iOS versions >= 10.0. To support older operating systems, the icon may be required in the bundle outside of an asset catalog. Make sure the Info.plist file includes appropriate entries referencing the file. See [https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/user_interface"](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/user_interface%22)

**Here is the steps what I did so far:**

**First Step:**

I setup the certificates and connect the certificates to the app store connect which is all fine and working this the first thing that I do.

**Second Step:**

**Changing the Project Identification Through XCode Application**

Bundle Identifier: com.xxx.xxx

Version: 0.1.0

Build: 1

**Deployment Info**

IOS 14.3

- Iphone
- Ipad

**Project Format:**

- XCode 12.0-Compatible

Folder Structure Images:

[image: Assets]

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of your xcassets file where the icon is?

Comment: sure @johnnykehr i will show you my work that I already did.

Comment: I already add @johnnykehr the folder structure of my appicons

Answer (score -1):

Seems like you are missing app icons in specied dimensions. Here is a tutorial for adding app icons : [Tutorial video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6kD1IZfGsWQ)

Comment: I already add the icons still same error

Comment: @DevGe have you checked this similar thread? MIght help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43942787/missing-required-icon-file-the-bundle-does-not-contain-an-app-icon-for-iphone/47007270

Comment: @DevGe have you checked this similar thread? MIght help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43942787/missing-required-icon-file-the-bundle-does-not-contain-an-app-icon-for-iphone/47007270

Answer (score -1):

You just need image of 1024x1024 size then you can generate the required icons for you app from [here](https://appicon.co/)

Comment: I already add the app icons but still same error