# How to correctly update the Assets.xcassets in old Swift Project with new support added and Deployment for iOS 15.0+ devices?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, icons

Recently, one the old projects developed in Swift required new icons for achieving and launching it in flight test but it has no support for iOS 15.0 + AppIcon.

**What i Tried and issue:**

1. Converted the images and imported the images in AppIcon but it shows no linkage

also tried adding all png files to iconImages in info.plist individually too

2. Used Icon Generator to convert original image to required conditions for following images::
3. Tried https://stackoverflow.com/a/47007270/17484834 's fix but it gives below error while suppressing other errors.
   [image]

> An app icon measuring 1024 by 1024 pixels in PNG format for Asset
> Catalog of apps built for iOS, iPadOS, or watchOS
>
> an app icon for iPad of exactly '152x152' pixels, in .png format for
> iOS versions >= 10.0. To support older operating systems, the icon may
> be required in the bundle outside of an asset catalog
>
> an app icon for iPad of exactly '167x167' pixels, in .png format for
> iOS versions supporting iPad Pro
>
> an app icon for iPhone / iPod Touch of exactly '120x120' pixels, in
> .png format for iOS versions >= 10.0

**Currently i have following in my AppIcon ::**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working(Easy) Solution:

- Create new project
- Migrate all the files(except the AppIcons) to the new project
- Download all the pods mentioned in the old pod file
- Copy all the resolution AppIcon files from old project to new project
- Clean build
- Run the project

Other Solution:

- Copying the Assets folder from any other project to the project and copy paste the required AppIcon files