# Problem with publishing Xamarin iOS app to App Store

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I just upgraded Xcode and Xamarin iOS to a newer version, and I face problem as in the image below. I am stuck in it for a long time. Can anyone help me?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hey welcome to StackOverflow. The error clearly states that you have some app icons missing. Add those in the project, and you'll be good to go.

Comment: @badhangganesh is not as easy as you said, I check the file appicon on the Assets.xcassets folder all of them are full

Comment: can you show us the assets folder

Comment: @NguyễnSỹThành Then add a screenshot of your xcassets as well, here.

Comment: @badhanganesh done! It is above

Comment: There's a new guideline for iPhoneX .Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18736954/missing-recommended-icon-file-the-bundle-does-not-contain-an-app-icon-for-iph

Answer (score 2):

You must add app icons to proceed , or either some bundle settings are not recognizing the app icons you have added already.

Application Icon - Every iOS app must define an application icon. This is the icon that the user will tap from the iOS home screen to launch the app. Additionally, this icon is used by Game Center, if applicable.

Take a look at this thread for Xamarin where all of it is included , Good Luck !

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/images-icons/app-icons?tabs=macos

Comment: hi @Anjula S, thank for response , I understand what is app icon, I'm not newbie . I did not face this problem in the old version (Xcode and Xamarin IOS )

Comment: any chance you remember what version you were using?